# Toggle Button inside the usercontrol inside another usercontrol is not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having two toggle buttons one in the outside usercontrol in the control template of the tabcontrol

Here is the code of the TabControl

```
<TabControl Name="ConnectionsTab" BorderThickness="0" Background="White">
                    <TabControl.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">  
<Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <WrapPanel  Grid.Column="0">
                                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius="10">
                                                        <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                                    <Border Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                                            <ToggleButton Name="OpenPopupButtonConnectionList" Background="White" BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30" ClickMode="Hover">
                                                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                                                    </Style>
                                                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                                                                <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Background="White" Foreground="Black" Kind="ArrowDropDown" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="18" />
                                                                </Grid>
                                                            </ToggleButton>
                                                            <Popup Name="PresetPopupConnectionList" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=OpenPopupButtonConnectionList, Path=IsChecked}"   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=OpenPopupButtonConnectionList}"    AllowsTransparency="True"   PopupAnimation="Slide"    StaysOpen="False" >
                                                                <ListBox Name="ConnectionList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"  Background="White" SelectionChanged="ConnectionList_SelectionChanged" MaxHeight="300" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedIndex="-1">
                                                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
                                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                                </ListBox>
                                                            </Popup>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Border>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </WrapPanel>
                                            <Border x:Name="contentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                        <Grid Background="White">
                                            <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="#1b9ed2" Margin="6,0,12,0" Background="White">
                                                <ContentPresenter Height="30" x:Name="ContentSite" ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,15,5,-5">
                                                </ContentPresenter>
                                            </Border>
                                            <Button  Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Name="TabCloseButton" Click="TabCloseButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ToolTip="Close" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Padding="0">
                                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Close" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                            </Button>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="TabIndex" Value="0">
                                                <Setter TargetName="TabCloseButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold" />
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                        </Style>
                    </TabControl.Resources>
                </TabControl>
```

I have added another usercontrol in the connectionspage as the first tabitem

```
      public ConnectionsPage(PMPResponse response)
        {
            this.response = response;
            InitializeComponent();
            tabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Connections", Content = new ResourceAccountDisplayUserControlCopy(response), TabIndex = 0 });
            ConnectionsTab.ItemsSource = tabItems;
            ConnectionsTab.SelectedIndex = 0;
            LoadResourceUserControl();
        }
```

I have another popup inside the inner usercontrol

```
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton Name="OpenPopupButtonUserProfile" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20">
                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Background="White" Foreground="Black" Kind="ArrowDropDown" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="18" />
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <Popup Name="PresetPopupSort" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=OpenPopupButtonUserProfile, Path=IsChecked}"   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=OpenPopupButtonUserProfile}"    AllowsTransparency="True"   PopupAnimation="Slide"    StaysOpen="False" >
                                <ListBox Background="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0.5" Margin="15,0,15,0" Padding="5">
                                    <ListBox.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                        </Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        </Style>
                                    </ListBox.Resources>
                                    <ListBoxItem Height="25" Padding="5,0,5,0">
                                        <Button Height="20" Padding="0" Name="SortAscending" Click="SortAscending_Click" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="Gray">Ascending</Button>
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                    <Separator Height="0.5" Margin="-8,2,-7.6,2"/>
                                    <ListBoxItem Height="25" Padding="5,0,5,0">
                                        <Button Height="20" Padding="0" Name="SortDescending" Click="SortDescending_Click" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="Gray">Descending</Button>
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                </ListBox>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
```

When I click the inner usercontrol's toggle button the popup appears, when I click the outer toggle button the popup appears.

But Once the outer toggle button is clicked. when the inner toggle button is clicked, The popup inside the inner usercontrol is not showing. but the inner toggle button returns true. The toggle button is getting checked when the outer toggle button is clicked both the popup shows simultaneously.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Double check the code you posted. The first section doesn't make sence as you have a `Setter` directly inside of `TabControl.Resources`.

Comment: @KeithStein sorry bro i missed a line while pasting <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">  
 Now i have edited the question.